# Using jQuery load function as an absolute path

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, load

I have several pages and these pages can be accessed either directly, or from an iFrame. The part where the page can be loaded as an iFrame is used for some functionality that I need.

The problem is, that when I use the .load() function in jQuery, the stylesheets, scripts, some images, etc are not being found because the .load() tries to load everything as a relative path from where it is called.

I need to load the pages in the iFrame kind of like a snapshot, which means that they should behave the same way as if they were accessed directly.

Trying to summarize, this is the problem:

The file is located as follows:

```
http://localhost/www/folders/myfolder/myfile.html
```

The index file from where the .load() function is called is in the root, i.e.

```
http://localhost/www/index.php
```

myfile.html contains links like:

```
css/style.css
js/script.js
```

There, these are located at:

```
http://localhost/www/folders/myfolder/css
http://localhost/www/folders/myfolder/js
```

Therefore, when the .load() function loads the file from the root folder, these are not found because they are read as follows:

```
http://localhost/css/ instead of http://localhost/folders/myfolder/css
```

How can I get around this?

Many thanks

Comment: Do you include CSS and JS files in the head section of myfile.html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could add a [base tag](http://htmldog.com/reference/htmltags/base/) to your loaded page with jQuery

```
      $("head").append("<base href="http://localhost/folders/myfolder/" />");
```

depending on the loading order you should play with this. (I am not sure if the css needs to be loaded BEFORE or AFTER this has been set)

Comment: This worked. However it works once every two clicks. For some reason, when I click to load the iFrame again, the stylesheets and scripts disappears.

Comment: It also appears that it is not working in Firefox. It is working fine in Chrome

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this,

```
<?php
define('file_path_css','folder/myfolder/css');

include file_path_css;
```

?>

this might work..

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like in your myfile.html, you just need to add "folder/myfolder/" to your stylesheet and script paths.